# Multiple ScreenShot

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, screenshot

I'm trying to make an application which takes multiple screenshots with different names and saves them on my desktop or wherever.

Can some one please help me. I think I can use it with loop but I don't know how to do it

I have this code of screenshot :

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
    bmp.Save("screenshot.png");  // saves the image
}
```

Comment: How do you plan on limiting the number of screenshots? Do you want it to take only 5 screenshots (or whatever number you decide on)? Should it keep running until the user presses a button? Something else?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How often do you need to take a screenshot? You probably need a Timer control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make a Bitmap array , then use a for loop create the screenshots and name them using the loop index.

then to save it use Bitmap.save(location);

something like

```
Bitmap[] screenshot = new Bitmap[10];
String name = "Screenshot";    

for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
{

 screenshot[i] = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
 screenshot[i].Save("PATH" + name + i);

}
```

Comment: I Think Ur Answer is Best for me I will Try then Tell u what happen

Comment: thanks alot . but i face one more prob that its taking all picture at once :( I dont need that i need 1 picture in 1 minute

Comment: use System.Threading.thread.Sleep(60000); at the end of the for loop , or even better you should use a timer , and place the screenshot code in the Timer_Tick event.

Comment: i use timer but how can i change name i just get this problem . when timer runs it replace old picture

Comment: Well that's because the filename you use to save the screenshot stays the same. You need to use a variable that changes on each tick , like a counter. Add one to the counter on each loop , and add the counter value to the file name.